# How to fill an Apple Watch with music with a small capacity iPhone?

Tags: music, apple-watch

It looks like the only way to add music to an Apple Watch is via the Watch app on iPhone (I'm not an Apple Music subscriber). Thus the music to be added to Apple Watch already needs to be on the iPhone. It's not possible to add music from an iPad or directly from a Mac, correct?

Where does that leave me with my old iPhone 6s with only 16Gb? Of the 16Gb only about 4-5Gb are usable if I were to uninstall all apps; the rest is occupied by iOS. Does that mean, I won't be able to put more than 4Gb of music on my Apple Watch? Or is it possible to copy my music over in chunks of 4Gb, as stressful as that would be? Thus what I mean is, when I delete the music from my iPhone, will it be deletet from my Apple Watch as well once I sync more music to it? Or will it stay on the Apple Watch in addition to the newly synced music?